# Accessing PHP page from C# getting different result than browser

Tags: c#, php, json, web

I'm tryng a simple access to one payground PHP page returning a json string.
Accessing the page from Chrome the result is ok, while accesing via WebClient or HttpClient the response text is not the same.
Please, feel free to sugget what is wrong in my code and why the result is not the same as browser.
Thank you in advance.

```
    public static string GetPHP()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string url = "http://twintrade.freecluster.eu/jobs/demojson.php";
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            return json;
            /*  PHP:
                  <?php
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');

                    class Fruit 
                    {
                      public $name;
                      public $color;

                      function set_color($color) { $this->color = $color; }
                      function set_name($name) { $this->name = $name; }
                      function get_name() { return $this->name; }
                    }

                    $apple = new Fruit();
                    $apple->set_name('Apple');
                    $apple->set_color('Red');

                    $banana = new Fruit();
                    $banana->set_name('Banana');
                    $banana->set_color('Yellow');

                    $fruits = array($apple, $banana);

                    echo json_encode($fruits);

                    ?>
            
                Chrome returns: [{"name":"Apple","color":"Red"},{"name":"Banana","color":"Yellow"}] 
                
                json = "<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" >
                        </script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}
                        function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)
                        e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
                        b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("e15e41daca70a9fe7a7afd1ef557d727");
                        document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; 
                        path=/"; location.href="http://twintrade.freecluster.eu/jobs/demojson.php?i=1";</script>
                        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
                        </body></html>"
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you request that URL from a browser the script generates a cookie and redirects you back to the page. The cookie is what determines if you get the JSON or not. The WebClient is not going to run the javascript and follow the redirect.

Comment: Thank you Scott for your comment, I had same result with HttpClient and/or HttpRequest too, probably for same reason. Which solution do you suggest to get the proper response?

Comment: If you grab the `__test` cookie from a browser request and send it with your requests from  the WebClient or HttpClient you should get JSON back.

Comment: Thank you Scott for your valuable suggestion. Anyway the complete solution I found works only using the WebBrowser control (seems related to javascript capabilities not present in WebRequest/HttpClient/WebClient). For anybody interested, use Content-Type: text/html instead of application/json to avoid any IE prompt, provide cookie to WebBrowser in Navigate method and read DocumentText property after DownloadComplete event.